# What’s a good statistical test to measure difference in proportions for the same sample for a Pre and Post analysis

Tags: statistics

I am trying to measure lift in product adoption rate (in %) for the same group of people, pre and post a marketing campaign.

1) How to determine minimum sample size needed to do a pre/post analysis?

2) Which test to use for a pre/post analysis on this metric (it’s a %) for the same group of people.

Comment: Maybe this can help http://www.statstutor.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/paired-t-test.pdf

Comment: Thanks so much! Curious if we can do a paired t test on proportions?

Comment: I can see this approach to measure before and after for observations, but how about measuring before and after percentages?

Comment: I don't quite understand the quantities of your problem. Can you be more specific? For example, you observe $X_1,...,X_n$ and then transform it into $X_i-\bar{X}$, $i=1,...,n$. I'm not saying that is what you are doing, just giving an example of a concrete definition of the measures (or quantities) of the problem.